# PHP $_POST which array item is passed?

Tags: php, arrays, post

I have a problem with the $_POST, I am writing an admin screen and outputting a list of notes for the user to be able to edit or delete.  What I output to the screen is the note "title" and note "content", and then 2 buttons for "edit" and "delete".  I also put the note "id" but this is hidden.
Obviously the number of records read and output varies but when the user clicks on a "delete" button how do I pass the correct "id" to the "delete" process?

The code I have to output the screen is:

```
<form name="sticky2" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
<?php 
      $i = 0;
      foreach($stickynotes as $notes)
      {
        echo $i . " - " . $notes['id'];  \\this line is just testing
?>
        <li>
          <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="<?php echo $notes['id'] ?>">

          <h2><?php echo $notes['title'] ?></h2>
          <p><?php echo $notes['content'] ?></p>
          <br>
        </li>
        <input type="submit" name="edit" class="StickyBtn StickyBlue" value="Edit" />
        &nbsp;&nbsp
        <input type="submit" name="delete" class="StickyBtn" value="Delete" />
        <br><br>
        &nbsp
<?php
        $i++;
      } 
?>
      </form>
```

with the delete process as follows:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
  if($_POST['delete']=='Delete')
  {
    echo $_POST['id'];  // Line only used for testing
    $query="DELETE FROM notes WHERE id = :id";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query);
```

the following line uses ['0'] which I know is the first record of the 
$notes array but I was just ensuring all the delete code worked and this
is the detail that is causing me the problem

```
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']['0'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
    try
    {
//     $stmt->execute();    // actual delete commented out while testing
    }

    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
      $msg = "STICKY NOTE NOT Found";
      //user friendly message and error handling here
    }
    header('Location: stickynotes.php' );
  }
}
```

I do not understand how does the delete process actually know which record it has to delete or is my process wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you'll have is that your form includes ALL the IDs and any of those submit buttons will affect all of them. The easiest way to do it is probably to move the `<form>` tag to inside your loop, so each item has a different form. Then you have independent delete buttons with separate ID fields (which then won't have to be an array since each form has only one ID attached too).